# How do I set fixed table's size after clicking 'expand' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table which is hidden by default and can only be seen after clicking "expand" button. The problem is when I click the button, the whole `tr` where this button is located messes up. Here's what I mean

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.partTableContent').hide();
  $('.expandButton').click(function() {
    // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
    $(this).closest('tr').next(' tr').find('div.partTableContent').slideToggle(750);
  });
});
```

```css
<style>.partsTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForPartsTable {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="partTableDiv">
    <table class="partsTable" style="width: 100%; height: 30vh">

      <tr>

        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="expandButton">Expand button</button></td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="editButton">edit</button></td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="removeButton">remove</button></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class="partTableContent">
            <table style="width: 100%">

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> table's tr </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </div>

</body>
```

See? When I click expand button, the whole `tr's` (where this button is located) height shrinks. Especially noticeable when click "Full page". How can I avoid it and make it the height static?

Comment: it bcoz of the height: 30vh, i guess remove that and check

Comment: But what if I want it to be always equal 30?

Comment: then give a height for the first `tr` say `height: 50px;`

Comment: Yup, thank you very much, it works. Please provide it as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: I had added it as an answer, plz check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz give a height for the first tr say height: 50px;

```
<table class="partsTable" style="width: 100%;">

      <tr style="height: 30vh">

        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="expandButton">Expand button</button></td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="editButton">edit</button></td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="removeButton">remove</button></td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: It's better to remove the height from table style and leave it only in the first tr